# Java Socket Handshake OK, But No Other Data. Router or Java (or myself) To Blame?

Tags: java, sockets, router, objectinputstream

I'm trying to set up a server/client connection in Java.
I've connected my PC directly to the DSL, and it works fine through Windows 10 firewall. I reconnect to my TP-Link Archer C9 router with Virtual Server set for port 4023 and 4024. I get a `SocketTimeoutException` on the Client Side.

And Wireshark gives me a bunch of TCP Retransmissions saying 'hello server' after the handshake from the Client, when I filter for port 4023:

Server code:

```
public class ServerTester {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
   try {
        final int PORT = 4023;
        ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(PORT, 100, null);
        System.out.println("Waiting for clients...");

        while (true)
        {                                               
            Socket s = server.accept();             
            System.out.println("Client connected from " + s.getLocalAddress().getHostName());                   
            ServerClient chat = new ServerClient(s);
            Thread t = new Thread(chat);
            t.start();
        }
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
         e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }    
}
```

Server Client:

```
public class ServerClient implements Runnable {

    private Socket socket;  
    public ServerClient(Socket s) {
    socket = s;
 }

@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        System.out.println("ObjectInputStream from inputStream created");
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        System.out.println("ObjectOutputStream created");
        String input = (String) ois.readObject();
        System.out.println("received: " + input); 
        oos.writeObject("hello yourself!");
        oos.flush();
        input = (String) ois.readObject();
        System.out.println(input);
        oos.writeObject("this is my second message");
        oos.flush();
        ois.close();
        oos.close();
        socket.close();

    } 
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
  }
}
```

Client Code:

```
public class ClientTester {

private final static int PORT = 4023;
private final static int LOCAL_PORT = 4024;
private final static String HOST = //removed for this post;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    try {
        Socket s = new Socket(HOST, PORT, InetAddress.getByName(HOST),       LOCAL_PORT);
        s.setSoTimeout(5000);
        System.out.println("You connected to " + HOST);         
        ClientClient client = new ClientClient(s);          
        Thread t = new Thread(client);
        t.start();

    } 
    catch (Exception noServer)
    {
        System.out.println("The server might not be up at this time.");
        System.out.println("Please try again later.");
                    noServer.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Client Client:

```
public class ClientClient implements Runnable {

private Socket socket;

public ClientClient(Socket s)
{
    socket = s;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        System.out.println("ObjectOutputStream from inputStream created");
        oos.writeObject("hello server");
        oos.flush();

        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        System.out.println("ObjectInputStream from inputStream created");
        String input = (String) ois.readObject();
        System.out.println(input);
        oos.writeObject("here is my second message to the server");
        oos.flush();
        input = (String) ois.readObject();
        System.out.println(input);
        oos.close();
        ois.close();
        socket.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
  }
}
```

The server console says:

```
run:

Waiting for clients...

Client connected from Ben
```

The client console says:

```
run:

You connected to //removed for post

ObjectOutputStream from inputStream created

    java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:170)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.read(ObjectInputStream.java:2320)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(ObjectInputStream.java:2333)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readShort(ObjectInputStream.java:2804)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:802)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:299)
    at clienttester.ClientClient.run(ClientClient.java:33)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Can my router's firewall be the culprit? It seems like it is allowing back and forth communication until the `ObjectInputStream` is being created.
Then is it a stupid Java error I'm making? As I said earlier, it works when I remove the router from the system.  I'm completely baffled.

This is my first question, from a longtime leacher. Thanks for all your help Stack Overflow!

Comment: Are you sure this is the real code? You should normally create the `ObjectOutputStream` *before* the `ObjectInputStream` at *both* ends. Also 5 seconds is rather short for a read timeout.

Comment: If we can believe the code and the other evidence, then the client side output stream is being created before it attempts to create its input stream.  That means that it can't deadlock.

Comment: I have read comments from other questions on the site about creating the ObjectOutputStream first.  I changed my code to do this. Unfortunately, I have the same problem.  I appreciate your comments.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Sorry for the brief reply, I'm on a mobile, but the problem is that your while loop is in the wrong place. Socket.accept is a blocking operation for a client connection. The client connection is made, then closed,and the code is done. I'll try to expand on the answer when i get to a desktop.

Comment: This doesn't make sense so far.

Comment: Interestingly enough, it works fine on my local machine. Perhaps not specifying a local port when constructing the Socket in the ClientTester?

Comment: That helps to know it is working on your machine. I'm more convinced now it is my router. I'm puzzled that it would allow the handshake to take place, but nothing else.  Thanks for your comments.

Comment: It was my router.  My IDE (Netbeans) was running the server and client code at the same time.  It appears that the TP-Link Archer C9 has loopback disabled for security purposes. It was allowing the socket handshake for some reason but then blocking information coming back.
I ran the same program from my Android phone using AndroidStudio as the client and my PC with Netbeans as the server and it worked fine.
Thanks for testing this at home @Zymus. Knowing you got it to work made me more suspicious of my router.  And thanks to everybody for their comments.